# Conditions of dimensions of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am supposed to solve the following question:

> If a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}_{m,n}$ have a basis, which
> conditions must its dimensions fulfill?

I know that vectors have to fulfill the linear independence property and the spanning property. But is there any conditions for dimensions?

Thanks

Comment: What does "a matrix is to have a basis" mean ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe that it does have basis, I updated my post

Comment: Yes, but what does that mean that "a matrix has a basis" ? Do you mean that the column of a matrix form a basis ? Or the rows ? Or something else ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I mean that row of a matrix form basis